# Dockerfile and docker compose with node alpine

Tags: docker

this is my **docker file:**

```
#building code
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/api/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/api

WORKDIR /home/node/api

COPY ormconfig.json .env package.json yarn.* ./

USER node

RUN yarn

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD node dist/src/index.js
```

and this is my **docker compose:**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    container_name: 'db'
    ports:
      - '${DB_PORT}:5432'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}

  api:
    image: ci-api
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}'
volumes:
  db_data:
```

and i create my image with docker build docker build -t ci-api .

but if I make any changes to my project and use my docker build again it is not updating in the container

Comment: Where is the service for Node in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: api:
    image: ci-api
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}'

Comment: What's the actual set of commands you're running?  What behavior are you seeing (or not)?

Comment: I use:
docker build -t ci-api.

and docker-compose up -d,
when I have any changes to the files I use the docker build -t ci-api again, and when I use the docker compose up -d
files are not being updated

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been documented in [docker/compose#4337](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4337), and the proposed fix is to use the flag `--renew-anon-volumes` in `docker-compose up`. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) for `docker-compose up`.

You might consider changing your `docker-compose.yml` file to reference the Dockerfile in your `api` service. Then `docker-compose up` will build the image if it has to, and you don't have to build it yourself.

```
api:
  build:
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    context: .
...
```

Comment: for some reason this is not working and still does not update my files